# Input se invalida cuando deshabilito el mismo - Angular

Tags: angular

Compañeros, tengo un formulario de tipo **Template Driven** en el cual tengo *N* inputs y algunos `select`, los cuales valido con los bienamados `valid` y `pristine` de la siguiente forma

```
<div class="form-group" [ngClass]="{ 'has-error': !officeState.valid && !officeState.pristine }">
   // Input
</div>
```

La validación se realiza de forma correcta; sin embargo, **ocurre algo extraño al deshabilitar los mismos inputs**.

La lógica es que se rellenen los inputs/select señalados para realizar una búsqueda, una vez devuelve datos estos filtros se deshabilitan para evitar realizar cambios en los mismos de la siguiente manera

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputOffice" name="office" [(ngModel)]="current.office" #officeState="ngModel" [disabled]="officeDisabled" >
```

Inferirán que el *flag* que estoy utilizando (*officeDisabled*) lo seteo según mi necesidad.

El problema pasa que cuando hago la deshabilitación de estos elementos - ojo que no es una limpieza de campo, por lo que el valor se mantiene - me marca como si `valid` y `pristine` fueran falsos y me muestra el estilo que definí para ese caso.

Espero haberme explicado lo más claro posible, ante cualquier duda estaré súper atento.

Agradecido como siempre :)

Comment: ¿Y si en lugar de disabled los marcas como readonly?

Comment: @PabloLozano el problema pasa es que entre esos inputs existen `select` y a estos no se les puede aplicar un **readonly**. Editaré la pregunta, porque es una observación importante

Comment: Con un formulario reactivo es mucho más sencillo gestionar esto... no podrías cambiar el actual a reactivo?

Comment: Por tiempos de desarrollo me es imposible migrar a ese tipo de formulario, sin embargo ya pude solucionar el inconveniente. Publicare la respuesta. Agradecido Pablo!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En los comentarios el colega **Pablo**, hizo que se me encendiera la ampolleta y pude resolver el problema de la siguiente manera

```
<fieldset [disabled]="condicion">
   <input>
</fieldset>
```

En resumen, envolviendo el elemento en un `fieldset` y aplicando el atributo `disabled` a dicho elemento pude obtener la funcionalidad que quería y que al mismo tiempo *no tuviera incoherencias al validar el formulario*.

Puede no ser la alternativa más sofisticada, pero es lo que se me ocurrió después de largo rato investigando sobre alguna posible solución.